# Why is my robot moving so slow with MoveIt?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My robot is running slower than it should. It can move much faster. How can I make it go at full speed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346203/why-is-my-robot-moving-so-slow-with-moveit?/) by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2180 on 2020-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, the velocity and acceleration is set to 10% of the robot's maximum in MoveIt (starting from Noetic). You can change the values in your code with [this C++](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#a0eec941ccbfa23260196196ce7a8dd17) and [this Python](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_commander/html/classmoveit__commander_1_1move__group_1_1MoveGroupCommander.html#a020b41d385657da906d746f97dcab4a6) function, or change the default value in the `joint_limits.yaml` file in your `moveit_config` package.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to what @fvd writes, also check whether the robot model has appropriate `velocity` and `acceleration` limits configured.

If it doesn't, MoveIt (or actually: the time-parameterisation plugins) will assume a default of `1.0 rad/s` and `1.0 rad/s^2` for all joints without limits:

- [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ab3b5a858be329706be8763a6c65d8a1c38e992c/moveit_core/trajectory_processing/src/iterative_time_parameterization.cpp#L43-L44) for the `IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization`
- [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ab3b5a858be329706be8763a6c65d8a1c38e992c/moveit_core/trajectory_processing/src/iterative_spline_parameterization.cpp#L42-L43) for the `IterativeSplineParameterization`
- [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ab3b5a858be329706be8763a6c65d8a1c38e992c/moveit_core/trajectory_processing/src/time_optimal_trajectory_generation.cpp#L941) and [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ab3b5a858be329706be8763a6c65d8a1c38e992c/moveit_core/trajectory_processing/src/time_optimal_trajectory_generation.cpp#L948) for the `TimeOptimalTrajectoryGeneration`

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4